# Web Service betweet two machines run on local

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, web

I'm working an a Web/Mobile Application.
Desktop is made with Laravel 5.1 and Oracle 11g express Edition.
Mobile is made on Android.

I'm using two computers, both of them are on local (Android and PHP).

All works fine on the desktop application.

Now it's time to connect my Android App to the database, to do so, i have to implement a Web Service.

How can i get the URL of the web service and use it on the other machine for android?

How can i test my webservice ?

Comment: thanks but i already did these steps , now i want to use the WebService on the Android App witch is on another machine.

Comment: You can use apps like POSTMAN or SoapUI to test your web service. You need to check your routes file to know your URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For trying Web Service locally,

1. Both your device needs to be in the same network.
2. The API calls will be like: `<YOUR.IP.ADDRS>/PATH` in you Android App Source Code.
3. You can even use [Postman REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), to test your app.

See, if that helps.